# Reac native error Execution failed for task ':react-native-rw-get-gallery-image:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Everything was working fine then all of sudden I got the following error while running app on simulator.

```
1 error
:react-native-rw-get-gallery-image:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-rw-get-gallery-image:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 18.372 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

Please help me to fix this error

Comment: Did you `Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output`?

Answer (score 0):

react-native-rw-get-gallery-image did not link properly, try linking it manually for iOS and ru react-native link react-native-rw-get-gallery-image